# Docker containers on custom network issues

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

My containers can not even ping anything, seems like someting is off with docker networking.

Containers can not ping 8.8.8.8

```
docker exec container_a ping 8.8.8.8
```

Containers can not ping eachother, but internal name resolution works

```
docker exec container_a ping container_b
PING container_b (172.200.0.6): 56 data bytes
```

External name resolution does not work

```
docker exec container_a nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

They are on the same network

```
docker network inspect docker_network | jq .[].Containers[].Name
"container_a"
"container_b"
```

Network creation docker-compose snippet

```
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.200.0.0/16
```

**Versions**

Docker version 19.03.11, build 42e35e61f3

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

**Things I've tried:**

Obviously docker service restart, and even machine restart

Reinstall docker, also deleting /var/lib/docker

```
apt remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose
```

Docker network restart

```
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
```

I'm absolutely at a loss, please help me

Sometimes a computer restart and a docker service restart fixes it, but I never know will it work after a restart